# Will IllegalArgumentException termination an app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, illegalargumentexception, terminate

The following code is from the official sample [projec](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#1)t.

Will `IllegalArgumentException` termination the app when R`esult.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))` is launched ?

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}


class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cityName = savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ARG_DETAILS_CITY_NAME)!!

    val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist")) // Will IllegalArgumentException termination an app ?
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: An Exception itself won't terminate an App.  An App is terminated when an Exception is **thrown** and **uncaught**. It doesn't matter what kind of Exception it is.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying? questions of the form "Will X happen if I do Y?" are easily answered by just doing it and see what happens. You can for example make sure that `destination` is null, or move the `Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))` code to another place where you are sure it will come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app will not crash (terminate) in this case, because the `IllegalArgumentException` exception is just being created, not thrown. The app will crash (terminate) if exception is thrown and isn't catched by `try-catch` operator, like the following:

```
throw IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist")
```